# uClibc vfork() is causing segmentation fault

Tags: linux, libc, openwrt, uclibc

I am using armv7 for openwrt development and facing a segfault caused by vfork.

I have wrote a small test program with the following segments:

```
    ...
    pid_t child_t;
    if((child_t = vfork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("error!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(child_t == 0)
    {
        printf("in child:pid =%d\n",getpid());
        sleep(2);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("in parent:child_t id = %d,pid = %d\n",child_t,getpid());
    }
    ...
```

The vfork() function always cause segfault, this is the gdb debug trace:

```
...
   (gdb) c
       Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbefffed4) at handler.c:33
       33            if((child_t = vfork()) < 0)
   (gdb) stepi 
       0x00008474 in vfork () at         libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/../../../../../../../libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/vfo        rk.S:71
   71        SAVE_PID
   (gdb) l
   66    
   67    #else
   68    __vfork:
   69    
   70    #ifdef __NR_vfork
   71        SAVE_PID
   72        DO_CALL (vfork)
   73        RESTORE_PID
   74        cmn    r0, #4096
   75        IT(t, cc)
  (gdb) b     libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/../../../../../../../libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/vfo    rk.S:72
       Breakpoint 2 at 0xb6fcf930: file     libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/../../../../../../../libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/vfo     rk.S, line 72.
  (gdb) disassemble
           0x00008584 <+40>:        bl      0x8444 <puts>
     => 0x00008588 <+44>:         bl      0x8474 <vfork>
           0x0000858c <+48>:         str    r0, [r11, #-12]
  (gdb)stepi
     ...
  (gdb) stepi 
       0x00008474 in vfork () at     libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/../../../../../../../libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/vfo    rk.S:71
       71              SAVE_PID
  (gdb) disassemble 
       Dump of assembler code for function vfork:
       =>  0x00008474 <+0>:   add  r12, pc, #0, 12
              0x00008478 <+4>:   add  r12, r12, #8, 20        ; 0x8000
              0x0000847c <+8>:   ldr    pc, [r12, #796]!        ; 0x31c
  (gdb) stepi
      …
   (gdb) disassemble
        Dump of assembler code for function vfork:
             0x00008474 <+0>:   add  r12, pc, #0, 12
             0x00008478 <+4>:   add  r12, r12, #8, 20        ; 0x8000
       => 0x0000847c <+8>:     ldr    pc, [r12, #796]!        ; 0x31c
    (gdb)c
       Continuing.
       Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
       0xffff0fe0 in ?? ()
    (gdb)
```

I have also found the vfork code at vfork.S:
    __vfork:

```
#ifdef __NR_vfork
     SAVE_PID
     DO_CALL (vfork)
     RESTORE_PID
     cmn    r0, #4096
     IT(t, cc)
 #if defined(__USE_BX__)
    bxcc    lr
 #else
     movcc    pc, lr
 #endif

     /* Check if vfork even exists.  */
    ldr     r1, =-ENOSYS
    teq     r0, r1
    bne     __error
#endif

    /* If we don't have vfork, use fork.  */
    DO_CALL (fork)
    cmn     r0, #4096

    /* Syscall worked.  Return to child/parent */
    IT(t, cc)
#if defined(__USE_BX__)
    bxcc    lr
#else
    movcc   pc, lr
#endif

__error:
    b    __syscall_error
#endif
```

Some more information -
when bypassing vfork like this -

```
   VFORK_LOCK;

-  if ((pid = vfork()) == 0) {  /* Child of vfork... */

+  // if ((pid = vfork()) == 0) {  /* Child of vfork... */

+        pid = syscall(__NR_fork, NULL);

+  if (pid == 0) {  /* Child of vfork... */
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`man (3) vfork`

> The  vfork()  function  shall be equivalent to fork(), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit() or one of the exec family of functions.

So in the child you can call `_exit` or `exec`.  That's it.

Comment: TL;DR: Don't call `vfork()`. It is not for you. :)

Comment: vfork() is used in uClibc implementation. Can I control it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to enable CONFIG_KUSER_HELPER flag.

From CONFIG_USERS_HELPERS.

```
If all of the binaries and libraries which run on your platform
 are built specifically for your platform, and make no use of
 these helpers, then you can turn this option off to hinder
 such exploits. However, in that case, if a binary or library
 relying on those helpers is run, it will receive a SIGILL signal,
 which will terminate the program.
```